# Getting this error while using javascript with html "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at random.js:1:1)"

Tags: javascript, npm

Hello everyone I am a beginer in web development. I am making a project where in I need to use a npm package `npm i link-preview-js`   in javascript file with html file and run it in browser 
random.js file

```
import { getLinkPreview, getPreviewFromContent } from "link-preview-js";

// pass the link directly
getLinkPreview("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MejbOFk7H6c").then((data) =>
  console.log(data)
);
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="random.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at random.js:1:1)`

I know i am an begginer their might be a silly error but please could you help me resolve it Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` is a feature of [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (and TypeScript modules).

While browsers do support it:

- they only do so if you [declare your script to be a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)
- they do not support Node.js style module resolution and require a URL which is either absolute, or starts with a `/` or a `.`.

It is more typical to use modules in combination with a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/).

That said, you need to [read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-preview-js):

> You cannot request a different domain from your web app (Browsers block cross-origin-requests). If you don't know how same-origin-policy works, here is a good intro, therefore this library works on node (back-end environments) and certain mobile run-times (cordova or react-native).

You might consider creating a webservice using Node.js and Express.js then accessing it with Ajax from your client side code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the js file and import something inside of the js file you need to import it into the html as a module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your file into a module or use the require syntax
For the first solution please add :

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

in your package.json file. I hope it solves your issue!

Comment: They are trying to run the code in a browser, not in Node.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).